# Do blind birds bob their head when they walk?

Tags: vision, ornithology

Birds try to keep their heads still for short periods of time between steps to improve their ability to see. You can find amusing videos of chickens used as small video camera stabilizers. But does this happen to blind birds? Is it something all birds do regardless of their ability to see?

Comment: I did not know that birds (mainly pigeon and a few other species) are moving their head the way they do when walking in order to improve their vision. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @Remi.b I wouldn't be surprised if it was influenced by [this question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21200/why-do-birds-move-their-heads-abruptly).

Comment: Oh indeed thank you. @user1306322 you should relate (and link) to this post (if it is indeed your reference) and make sure to not over interpret what is being said (it does not talk about walking).

Comment: My question was inspired mostly by [Mumbles, a chicken born without eyes](https://www.google.com/search?q=mumbles+chicken+with+no+eyes&tbm=isch) and prior knowledge about the reason why birds bob their heads. No SE questions were used as inspiration for this post. I'd appreciate if users did not assume unnecessary things for everyone's sake here.

Answer (score 5):

The forward thrusting movement so peculiar of pigeons and other fowl (Fig. 1) while walking is thought to be related to shifting the visual field. The less visible backward motion of the head is thought to be related to fixating the field of view [(Dunlap & Mowler (1931)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a334/0aac8d2a3675517a367d48e3338f22485643.pdf).

According to the meticulous observational study by [Dunlap & Mowler (1931)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a334/0aac8d2a3675517a367d48e3338f22485643.pdf), **blindfolded pigeons stop making head movements altogether while walking**. They stop their forward thrusting motion, the backward motion as well as more random scanning head movements. Hence, the authors conclude that the forward and backward jerking movements are related to vision, and not to hold their balance or whatsoever.

[image: ![enter image description here]
<sup>Fig. 1. Snapshots of a pigeon walking. The head thrusts forward in the middle frame. source: [Dunlap & Mowler (1931)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a334/0aac8d2a3675517a367d48e3338f22485643.pdf)</sup>

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Dunlap & Mowler, *J Comparative Psychol* (1931); **11**(1): 99-113](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a334/0aac8d2a3675517a367d48e3338f22485643.pdf)</sub>

Comment: Is there any other, more recent study on the subject? 1931 was long ago, and it would be strange if no one had investigated this ever again.

Comment: @RichardHardy not that I know of, no.

Comment: That was fast! Thanks! Does it not seem a bit weird that there are no newer studies? I assume we just might not know of them, but I am not a biologist (nowhere near).

Comment: @RichardHardy, yes there might be newer studies.  I must say it took me quite some time to find even one study addressing this. And unfortunately,  it's pretty dated indeed. But nonetheless, it was a well controlled study as far as I can see and it addressed the question here quite directly. And in fact,  I seriously doubt there is any newer study on this,  but I can't be sure.

Comment: @AliceD by any chance do you know how one could instigate researchers to organize such a study these days? Perhaps by sending some emails to parties interested in making viral study videos (the credible kind)?

Comment: [Here](https://youtu.be/_rAEyU3w7eY) is a related YouTube video bearing essentially the same message.